# How to display localized (best fit) units with Intl?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

When working with dates it automatically localizes them, i.e. my local date would be `YYYY-MM-DD` while with `en-US` locale I would receive `DD/MM/YY`.

When working with `length`, `area`, `weight`, `volume`, `temperature`, `time` and their compound units like `length-per-time` I can't find a similar feature in Intl API. I've been searching specs and github for whole day, but the closest thing I found was https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/32 :

```js
var f = Intl.UnitFormat(navigator.languages, {
  units: {
    {type: 'length', unit: 'bestFit'},
  }
});
f.format(2048); // would return '2 km' in en-US
```

Which seems to be gone after merging into "Intl.NumberFormat rev. 2".

So is there a way to avoid mapping every existing locale with every existing unit like in this example?:

```js
const format = unit => value =>
  new Intl.NumberFormat("en", {
    style: "unit",
    unit,
    notation: "compact",
    maximumSignificantDigits: 3
  })
  .format(value)


function fakeBestFit(value, locale) {
  // if US or any other imeprial system based locale
  if (locale || navigator.language === 'en-US') {
    const mile = 1609.34
    const yard = 0.9143977272588
    // const inch = ...
    // const foot = ...
    if (value >= mile) {
      return format("mile")(value / mile)
    } else if (value >= yard) {
      return format("yard")(value / yard)
    } else {
      // other units for locale i.e. inches and feet
    }
  } else {
    // for metric countries
    return format("meter")(value)
  }
}

console.log('expected: 1 m, received: ' + fakeBestFit(1))
console.log('expected: 1 km, received: ' + fakeBestFit(1000))
console.log('expected: 1 Mm, received: ' + fakeBestFit(1000000))
console.log('expected: 1 cm, received: ' + fakeBestFit(0.001))
console.log('expected: 1 mi, received: ' + fakeBestFit(1609.34, 'en-US'))
console.log('expected: 1 yd, received: ' + fakeBestFit(0.9143977272588, 'en-US'))
```

Comment: The difficulty with this sort of thing is it would either lead to recipes like "add 3.55oz of flour" or "drive 32.1869 kilometers", or lossy rounding of the actual data.

Comment: Also many units [aren't really localizable](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-such-a-weird-mix-of-metric-and-imperial-measurements-in-the-UK) as they depend on the thing being measured. Not just the UK: in the US we use liters for soda but gallons for milk ¯\_(ツ)_/¯